# Data is not inserting to database when image is null

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments, imageview

I want to store data into the database and want to upload an image in optional.

It means that if i am inserting the record without adding image then it will store in database without the image name.

right now when i am fill the data and insert an image then it is storing in the database if i don't select any image and i add only data then in database the data is not inserted and showing me blank value in every field

I tried a lot but not getting the required output.

My code **main.java**

```
    buy_image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
                edit.putInt("ImageID", 1);
                edit.commit();


            }
        });

        public void selectImage()
    {
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        /*i.putExtra("crop", "true");
        i.putExtra("outputX", 512);
        i.putExtra("outputY", 512);
        i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        i.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        i.putExtra("scale", true);
    */
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            int imgid = 0;
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};

           Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Log.d("Value", picturePath);
            fileName = new File(picturePath).getName();
            // imgname.setText(fileName);

            String fileNameSegments[] = picturePath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

            // MyParams.put("filename", fileName);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

            sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Image ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            imgid = sp.getInt("ImageID", 0);
            Log.d("IMGID", Integer.toString(imgid));


            BitmapFactory.Options options =null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, stream);

            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);


            if(imgid == 1) {
                buy_image1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                img1 = fileName;
                encodedStringIMG1 = encodedString;
            }else if(imgid == 2){

                buy_image2.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                img2 = fileName;
                encodedStringIMG2 = encodedString;

            }
        else{
                Log.d("IMGID","IMAGE ID IS 0");
            }
    }
    private void InsertWodinformation() {

        service(strwodname,strbranch,strcontactperson,strcontact,strwhatsapp,stremail,
                strspinnercity,straddress,opendate1,birthdate,ani,strpancard,strtinnumber,strbankname,strbankholdername,strbankac,
                strbankcity, strifsccode,strsecuritycheque,strrefrence1,strrefrence2,strremarks,img1,encodedStringIMG1,img2,encodedStringIMG2);
    }
private void service(
        String strwodname,String strbranch,
        String strcontactperson, String strcontact,
        String strwhatsapp, String stremail, String strspinnercity,
        String straddress, String opendate1, String birthdate, String ani,
        String strpancard, String strtinnumber, String strbankname, String strbankholdername
        ,String strbankac,String strbankcity, String strifsccode,String strsecuritycheque,String strrefrence1,
        String strrefrence2,String strremarks,String i1,String encode1,String i2,String encode2
  ) {

        class AddVisitclass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();


                /*param.put("firm", params[1]);
                param.put("oname", params[2]);
                param.put("pname1", params[3]);
                param.put("pname2", params[4]);
                */
                param.put("wname", params[0]);
                param.put("branch", params[1]);
                param.put("cname", params[2]);
                param.put("contact", params[3]);
                param.put("whatsapp", params[4]);
                param.put("email", params[5]);

                param.put("city", params[6]);
                param.put("address", params[7]);
                param.put("odate", params[8]);
                param.put("bdate", params[9]);
                param.put("adate", params[10]);
                param.put("pancard", params[11]);
                param.put("tinno", params[12]);
                param.put("bnm", params[13]);
                param.put("bank_ac_holder", params[14]);
                param.put("bank_ac_no", params[15]);
                param.put("bcity", params[16]);
                param.put("ifsc_code", params[17]);
                param.put("cheque", params[18]);
                param.put("ref1", params[19]);
                param.put("ref2", params[20]);
                param.put("remarks", params[21]);

                param.put("pan", params[22]);
                param.put("epan", params[23]);
                param.put("aadhar", params[24]);
                param.put("eaadhar", params[25]);
/*


                param.put("light", params[26]);
                param.put("elight", params[27]);

                param.put("vat", params[28]);
                param.put("evat", params[29]);

                param.put("vcard", params[30]);
                param.put("evcard", params[31]);

                param.put("shop", params[32]);
                param.put("eshop", params[33]);
*/



                param.put("username",uid);
                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(url_addwod, param);
                Log.d("Result", result);
                Log.d("Data", param.toString());
                return result;
            }
            //@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //loading.dismiss();


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "W.O.D. added successfully...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /* FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                TabFragment mFrag = new TabFragment();
                t.replace(com.Weal.sachin.omcom.R.id.framelayout, mFrag);
                t.commit();
                */
            }
        }
        AddVisitclass regi = new AddVisitclass();
        regi.execute(strwodname,strbranch,strcontactperson,strcontact,strwhatsapp,stremail,
                strspinnercity,straddress,opendate1,birthdate,ani,strpancard,strtinnumber,strbankname,strbankholdername,strbankac,
                strbankcity, strifsccode,strsecuritycheque,strrefrence1,strrefrence2,strremarks,i1,encode1,i2,encode2);
    }
```

And one more thing when image is uploading to the server it is generating the lower size but i want it in default size.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table you are trying to store into.

Comment: you are asking for api???

Comment: Use the mysql commandline tool so we can dig into the details of the database.

Comment: i am using version 5.5 not 5.7 and is this code is correct  or i need to change some code here??

Comment: i can't figure out where's the problem is in API or in code..

Comment: Is there at least a way of displaying the SQL that your code generates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143343/discussion-between-andie-and-rick-james).

Comment: Could you please help me on this??

Answer (score 5):

The best way to store images/files data is to save the images to the device storage resource (e.g internal memory or external),then you have the image URL/URI saved in your database (instead of having blob field in the database), and to display it all you have to do is to retrieve the file URL and display it on the device.

I hope this gives you a better solution for this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not experienced in Android development so excuse me for adding this solution without solving the issue you are facing in your code, but I saw your question about saving file to the database, the issue with it is you will end up with a huge database for saving few files, and for saving the file in a server, yes, sure thing, as I remember the company I was working for the had a media server to media files and they used it for IOS and Android too to save them some issues for the platform they are working on.

Comment: that approach though feasible is not exactly recommended , what happens when the source changes?

Comment: can you please look at my updated question ?? i jus update it and set bounty for it

Comment: what is the errors you got during the upload/saving? it might be related to the database columns, you might created it and set it to not allow null values, also there might be an error if you have hard-coded the upload process in which it takes 6 images and not less and not more. if you have any error displayed please provide them.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to save images are save them in your computer or device you are using and pass the path (location) of the image through a sql query to the database and when you want to access the image get the location of the image from the database and display.

following link will help you to understand
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: the problem i am facing is that when i am uploading one image then record is not storing into the database but when i insert all images then record is inserting to the database

Answer (score 2):

> You have to covert bitmap to BLOB format to save it ti db llook below
>   code :

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encodedData = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    dba.insertPhoto(byteArray);
```

Comment: yea this option is good, i was gonn say base64 but the space complexity is much larger

Comment: Now the image is storing in the server but the problem i am facing is that the image size is getting lesser size but i want image size as it is.

Comment: look I have edited and put code that I have used in my app, which saves photos perfectly

Comment: can you please look at my updated question ?? i jus update it and set bounty for it

Comment: yes, the answer what I gave is used in my app and I have not faced any issues, so I think it is correct

Comment: you can search the internet and youll find that this is the solutions most of the developers prefer

Comment: can you tell me where you are getting stuck

Answer (score 2):

Consider first compressing your images, to reduce the size of the image for storage. You have three options here, first you can get the base64 representation of the image, which is a string then store it , or get the byte array output and still store it. And lastly store the uri reference for the image located on the phone. Though i would not recommend this approach, because it is subjected to path changes and user deletion.

Here is a great library that uses google webp.WebP is a modern image format that provides superior lossless and lossy compression for images.WebP lossless images are 26% smaller in size compared to PNGs. WebP lossy images are 25-34% smaller than comparable JPEG images at equivalent SSIM quality index. [Link to library](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor).

Here is a galore of code snippets that can perform your request!

> ```
> private static String CompressJPEG(Bitmap bitmap) {
>         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
>         byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
>         return Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
>     }
>  private static byte[] CompressJPEGByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
>         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
>         return stream.toByteArray();
> ```

```
    }

 private static String CompressPNG(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

> ```
>   private static byte[] CompressPNGByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
>         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
>         return stream.toByteArray();
> ```

```
    }

   private static Bitmap RevertImageBase64(String encodedImage) {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    }

public static Bitmap RevertFromByteArray(byte[] arr) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arr, 0, arr.length);
    }
```

Here is also code to get the extension from a uri.

```
 public static void GetExtensionFromContentURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));

    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: do consider saving image on a external server by the way, last thing you want is to overhaul memory and storage causing a negative experience for the application user that is!

Comment: Now the image is storing in the server but the problem i am facing is that the image size is getting lesser size but i want image size as it is.

Comment: yup it is compressed

Comment: sorry i do not comprehend then?

Comment: can you please look at my updated question ?? i jus update it and set bounty for it

Comment: why are you sending the base64 representation to the server ,thats really big. any way for me to help you , there is two things needed to change , firstly switch to retrofit2 its rated as the best http tool for android, and also the remove the logic in the onActivityResult into its own method

Comment: so first familiarize yourself with retrofit2

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the size issue you mentioned, in onActivityResult(), the statement:

```
options.inSampleSize = 5;
```

could be the reason for the file to be smaller than the original image.

This is needed for the ImageView. Before compressing, keep a non compressed coopy for transmission to the server.

To troubbleshoot the insert of the image you need to post:

1. If the column in the database is defined as "not null"
2. A Log.d() of the value it is sending to the server when no picture is selected.
3. The code on the server that receives the data and performs runs the insert.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring code like below might help you. Don't take method names, variable names and other parts as a real example. I wanted to give you a bird-eye view of sample design.

```
//controller of user request.
handleRequest(){
    String imagePath=null;
    if(imageExists){ //if user sent image to server.
        imagePath=saveImageAndReturnImagePath(...);
    }

    saveRecordToDB(request.getText(), imagePath);
}


 //save image to disk and return image path.
private String saveImageAndReturnImagePath(...){
    //do image manipulation here, save image to disk, return path.
    return imagePath;
}

//insert a new record to db.
private void saveRecordToDB(String text, imagePath){
    Record a=new Record(text, imagePath);
    dao.save(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to cache images . is to use JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader
Here's an example :

```
       OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            return originalResponse.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).build();
        }
    });
    try{


        okHttpClient.setCache(new Cache(this.getCacheDir(), Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        OkHttpDownloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();
        picasso.load("pucul").error(R.drawable.teacher).into(imgvw);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
```

add this to your gradle file

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```

[Source :](https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader)